Can Caddy's data directory be shared among multiple replicas when doing Let's Encrypt?
I was wondering if the data folder for Caddy would work with multiple replicas of Caddy trying to do TLS verification with Lets Encrypt.
This was a limitation on Traefik unless you opt for the enterprise edition.

https://github.com/caddyserver/caddy/pull/2015 indicates that it supports a shared volume and will handle the locking as needed.
